# How can I create a Django model for a form in which users can choose to add more fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-formwizard

Is this the correct way to write out all the fields in **models.py** and **forms.py**? I am sure there must be a cleaner way to do this rather than individually listing out all fields and differentiating them with a number at the end.

I have looked into Django FormSets but I am not sure how I would use that with Django WizardForms.

Thank you

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    education_school            = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    education_degree            = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    education_field             = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_start             = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_end               = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_grade             = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    education_description       = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    education_school2           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    education_degree2           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    education_field2            = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_start2            = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_end2              = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_grade2            = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    education_description2      = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    education_school3           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    education_degree3           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    education_field3            = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_start3            = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_end3              = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_grade3            = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    education_description3      = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    education_school4           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    education_degree4           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    education_field4            = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_start4            = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_end4              = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_grade4            = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    education_description4      = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    education_school5           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    education_degree5           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    education_field5            = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_start5            = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_end5              = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    education_grade5            = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    education_description5      = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileFour(forms.Form):
    education_school        = forms.CharField()
    education_degree        = forms.CharField()
    education_field         = forms.CharField()
    education_start         = forms.ChoiceField(choices=years)
    education_end           = forms.ChoiceField(choices=years)    
    education_grade         = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    education_description   = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    education_school2       = forms.CharField()
    education_degree2       = forms.CharField()
    education_field2        = forms.CharField()
    education_start2        = forms.ChoiceField(choices=years)
    education_end2          = forms.ChoiceField(choices=years)    
    education_grade2        = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    education_description2  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    education_school3       = forms.CharField()
    education_degree3       = forms.CharField()
    education_field3        = forms.CharField()
    education_start3        = forms.ChoiceField(choices=years)
    education_end3          = forms.ChoiceField(choices=years)    
    education_grade3        = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    education_description3  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    education_school4       = forms.CharField()
    education_degree4       = forms.CharField()
    education_field4        = forms.CharField()
    education_start4        = forms.ChoiceField(choices=years)
    education_end4          = forms.ChoiceField(choices=years)    
    education_grade4        = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    education_description4  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    education_school5       = forms.CharField()
    education_degree5       = forms.CharField()
    education_field5        = forms.CharField()
    education_start5        = forms.ChoiceField(choices=years)
    education_end5          = forms.ChoiceField(choices=years)    
    education_grade5        = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    education_description5  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have ModelForm in django

```
class ProfileFour(form.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = '__all__'  # you wand all field
       # or 
       fields = ['education_school', 'education_degree' ..] # name the field you want
```

doc django's really good, read it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/

**edit**: for completed the answer of @Countour-Integral

```
class Profil(models.Model)
   username = models.charField()
   ...

class Education(models.Model)
    profil = models.ForeignKey(Profil)
    school = models.CharField()
    degree = models.IntegerField()
    field = models.CharField()
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()
    grade = models.CharField()
    description = models.textField()
```

Comment: Will this work for storing the education fields 5 times?

Comment: 5times and more  , check in  admin panel.

Comment: Tried it out but this seperates the education data into a different model with the same issue as before. I will have to copy every field 5 times, i.e. school1, school2, school3, etc... I am looking for a way to only write that once for each field like you wrote above.

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way. check the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at this the wrong way. Firstly, your model should be updated to reflect your use case. If you don't know the fields ahead of time, you can use a `JSONField` contained in an `ArrayField` e.g

`education = ArrayField(models.JSONField(default=dict), size=10, default=list)`

Now that we've got that out of the way, the better way to do what you want is to have `Education` as a model, and then the `Profile` model would have a foreign key to `Education`. ie

```
class Education(models.Model):
  school = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  degree = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  ...rest of fields
```

Then your `Profile` model would have:
`education = models.ForeignKey(Education, related_name="profile")`

To get a varying number of education forms, you should take advantage of [modelformset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/models/#modelformset-factory). Create your `EducationForm` as a normal modelForm instance, then:

```
EducationFormSet = modelformset_factory(Education, form=EducationForm, max_num=10, extra=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writting the same code 5 times you could just use a ManyToMany field.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    education_school            = models.ManyToManyField( blank=True)
    education_degree            = models.ManyToManyField( blank=True)
    education_field             = models.ManyToManyField( blank=True)
    education_start             = models.ManyToManyField( blank=True)
    education_end               = models.ManyToManyField( blank=True)
    education_grade             = models.ManyToManyField( blank=True)
    education_description       = models.ManyToManyField( blank=True)
```

- and then you could define each field seperately

```
class education_school(models.Model):
    education_school = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
```

and so on with the other fields